# one-to-One relationship, dropdownlist

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want a one-to-one relationship, between route and difficult level (simple, hard). I have these models:

```
public class Route
{

    [Key]
    public int routeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? UserProfileID { get; set; }
    public int? CountryID { get; set; }
    //public int? DifficultGradeID { get; set; }



    public virtual UserProfile userProfile { get; set; }
    public virtual Country country { get; set; }
    public virtual Difficult difficult { get; set; }
}

public class Difficult
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Route")]
     public int routeID { get; set; }
     public string DifficultName { get; set; }

     public virtual Route route { get; set; }

}
```

but every time I do Update-Databse, I get this error:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'routeID' on type 'ContosoUniversity.Models.Difficult' is not valid. 
>   The navigation property 'Route' was not found on the dependent type 'ContosoUniversity.Models.Difficult'. 
>   The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReName the virtual property in the Difficult class to be **R**oute instead of route.

Comment: Actually, on closer inspection, add the ForeignKey attribute to the virtual property and provide the property name, routeID.